# national language supported sort in Hive

Tags: hadoop, hive

Don't have to much experience with nls in hive. Changing locale in client linux shell doesn't affect the result.
Googling also doesn't help to resolve.

Created table in Hive:
    create table wojewodztwa (kod STRING, nazwa STRING, miasto_woj STRING) ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',';

loaded data:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INPATH ./wojewodztwa.txt OVERWRITE INTO TABLE wojewodztwa;
```

contents of file wojewodztwa.txt:

```
02,dolnośląskie,Wrocław
04,kujawsko-pomorskie,Bydgoszcz i Toruń
06,lubelskie,Lublin
08,lubuskie,Gorzów Wielkopolski i Zielona Góra
10,łódzkie,Łódź
12,małopolskie,Kraków
14,mazowieckie,Warszawa
16,opolskie,Opole
18,podkarpackie,Rzeszów
20,podlaskie,Białystok
22,pomorskie,Gdańsk
24,śląskie,Katowice
26,świętokrzyskie,Kielce
28,warmińsko-mazurskie,Olsztyn
30,wielkopolskie,Poznań
32,zachodniopomorskie,Szczecin    

beeline>  !connect jdbc:hive2://172.16.45.211:10001 gpadmin changeme org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver                      
Connecting to jdbc:hive2://172.16.45.211:10001
Connected to: Hive (version 0.11.0-gphd-2.1.1.0)
Driver: Hive (version 0.11.0-gphd-2.1.1.0)
Transaction isolation: TRANSACTION_REPEATABLE_READ
0: jdbc:hive2://172.16.45.211:10001> select kod,nazwa from wojewodztwa order by nazwa;                                          
+------+----------------------+
| kod  |        nazwa         |
+------+----------------------+
| 02   | dolnośląskie         |
| 04   | kujawsko-pomorskie   |
| 06   | lubelskie            |
| 08   | lubuskie             |
| 14   | mazowieckie          |
| 12   | małopolskie          |
| 16   | opolskie             |
| 18   | podkarpackie         |
| 20   | podlaskie            |
| 22   | pomorskie            |
| 28   | warmińsko-mazurskie  |
| 30   | wielkopolskie        |
| 32   | zachodniopomorskie   |
| 10   | łódzkie              |
| 24   | śląskie              |
| 26   | świętokrzyskie       |
+------+----------------------+
16 rows selected (19,702 seconds)
```

and it's not correct result, all words starting with language specific characters are at the and.

Answer (score 0):

Hive does not support [collations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collation). Strings will sort according to Java [String.compareTo](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#compareTo%28java.lang.String%29) rules.